# Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\****** \New Bitmap Image.bmp' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I am getting below error message while executing code:

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Project\Source \New Bitmap Image.bmp' because it is being used by another process.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


namespace MoveFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string SourceFile = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Project\Source ";
            string Destination = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Project\Destination";
            string[] piclist = Directory.GetFiles(SourceFile, "*.bmp");           

          foreach (string f in piclist)
          {
              SourceFile.Clone();
              Console.WriteLine(f);
              File.Copy(Path.Combine(SourceFile, f), Path.Combine(Destination, f), true);
          }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using this, this is to copy across one file.

Note: This is a code running on a button click on windows form.

```
OpenFileDialog obj = new OpenFileDialog();
        obj.ShowDialog();
        string startLoc = obj.FileName;
        string destinationlocation = @"D:\Pictures";
        string destinationfile = Path.Combine(destinationlocation, obj.SafeFileName);
        if (!Directory.Exists(destinationlocation))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationlocation);
        }
        File.Copy(obj.FileName, destinationfile);
```